# Is the first character in the URI part of a HTTP handler always a forward slash?

Tags: http, url, sinatra, uri, nancy

We are implementing a HTTP request handler subsystem in our project. The HTTP RFC says that the absolute path cannot be empty; if none is present in the original URI, it MUST be given as "/" (the server root).

#### Question:

Does this mean that these two browser requests are guaranteed to result in the same http request verb, uri and host?

Browser request 1:

```
http://www.foo.com/
```

Browser request 2:

```
http://www.foo.com
```

Http request (not tested, but I assume that this is the case):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.foo.com
```

#### Follow up questions:

If the above assumptions are correct, is the forward slash guaranteed to ALWAYS be the first character of the path in a correct HTTP request?

And the last question: In a framework like Ruby Sinatra, is it a safe assumption to say that the user should ALWAYS begin his or her handlers with a leading forward slash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do HTTP paths have to start with a slash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638278/do-http-paths-have-to-start-with-a-slash)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Follow Up Question:*

As far as I know:

http://www.foo.com/path

http://www.foo.com/path/

Are two different URLs

A Sinatra route for:

/path

Will not map to a request for URL that has a trailing /

In Nancy however, it doesn't matter if the trailing forward slash exists or not.

---

*Question:*

If you create a route for

path

It will map from the base URL, in the same way

/path

Will map.

Basically both are identical.

My personal preference however is to always have the leading forwardslash because it's like saying "The root URL followed by my defined route".

Comment: You say that /path and path are 'basically' identical. The question is if there can be a case when they do not catch the exact same set of URI and are 100% interchangable.

Comment: The question is not about a path with a trailing slash. In the question there is only the host to accompany the a root slash.

Comment: If I get an answer to if there can be a different use case for /path and path in sinatra, I can accept the answer.

Comment: In a request the first character is always a forward slash. It's the beginning of the path after the HOST. Sinatra (from my limited knowledge) must always start with a forward slash. Nancy you don't have to. (hope that makes sense)