# Do HTTP paths have to start with a slash?

Tags: file, http, web, path, protocols

I have a question regarding the HTTP format. The first line of a HTTP request looks something like this:

```
GET /path/to/resource.txt HTTP/1.1
```

or in other words:

```
METHOD URI HTTP-VERSION
```

Is it required that the `URI` starts with the `/` character so that `/path/to/resource.txt` would be the same as `path/to/resource.txt` and both are valid?

And if a leading `/` is not required, are `GET / HTTP/1.1` and `GET  HTTP/1.1` the same too? (two spaces between `GET` and `HTTP/1.1`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [RFC 7230, section 5.3 Request target](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3):

> Once an inbound connection is obtained, the client sends an HTTP
> request message (Section 3) with a request-target derived from the
> target URI.  There are four distinct formats for the request-target,
> depending on both the method being requested and whether the request
> is to a proxy.

> ```
> request-target = origin-form
> ```

```
                / absolute-form
                / authority-form
                / asterisk-form
```

You're talking about origin-form, described in [subsection 5.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1):

> When making a request directly to an origin server, other than a
> CONNECT or server-wide OPTIONS request (as detailed below), a client
> MUST send only the absolute path and query components of the target
> URI as the request-target.  **If the target URI's path component is
> empty, the client MUST send "/" as the path within the origin-form of
> request-target.**  A Host header field is also sent, as defined in
> Section 5.4.

> For example, a client wishing to retrieve a representation of the
> resource identified as

> ```
> http://www.example.org/where?q=now
> ```

> directly from the origin server would open (or reuse) a TCP
> connection to port 80 of the host "www.example.org" and send the
> lines:

> ```
> GET /where?q=now HTTP/1.1
> ```

```
 Host: www.example.org
```

And an "absolute path" is defined earlier in [section 2.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7) as

> ```
>  absolute-path = 1*( "/" segment )
> ```

So yes, *some* target identifier is required, the path is always prefixed with a slash, and if unknown, empty or inapplicable, it is `/`.

Comment: `To allow for transition to the absolute-form for all requests in some
   future version of HTTP, a server MUST accept the absolute-form in
   requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only send them in
   requests to proxies.` so this is debatable.