# how can I listen a path without '/' in http module

Tags: node.js, json, http

I can touch my code when http request look like this:

```
POST /init HTTP/1.1  
Host: 127.0.0.1  
Connection: keep-alive  
Content-Length: 1343
```

The http request looks like this:

```
POST init HTTP/1.1 // what different is : the path without a '/'  
Host: 127.0.0.1  
Connection: keep-alive  
Content-Length: 1343
```

My node.js code is:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('sth')
}).listen(3000);
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the code issuing the `init` request.

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if that is considered a valid HTTP request?

Comment: u r right.. but my client don't want to fix it, so I want to fit this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, see this question: [Do HTTP paths have to start with a slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638278/do-http-paths-have-to-start-with-a-slash)

Apparently, yes, the starting slash is required for it to be a valid HTTP request.

As this is technically invalid HTTP, most libraries won't support it.

It seems that Apache tolerates paths without slash... maybe using it as a reverse proxy as a workaround?

Another possibility would be to fork the HTTP server library and modify it to tolerate paths without slashes... you may want to look at this post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349656/implement-a-http-server-on-top-of-nodejs-tcp-apis-for-learning-purposes

Comment: i know that. it must start with a slash..but my client don't want to fix it. cry..cry..cry